# Examples of data collection methods about users and context in hospitals?

Tags: research, usability-study, data-collection

Can someone provide examples of field data collection methods about users and context in the health care domain more precisely in hospitals? And if possible what are the results of the research?

Answer (score 2):

This video from my local health care area may also help you. Stratford was one of the Top 7 Smartest Cities in the world in 2011 and again this year 2012. They use the use of technology to effectively recruit and make the patients overall experience better by making everything accessible to physicians.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iyQ8RVax80I

Comment: that's nice, I would really like to know what field work in UCD have been made for this project. Any Idea where I could find that?

Comment: Annie you may find some interesting tid bits in their new section http://www.hpha.ca/Default.aspx?cid=67&lang=1 am working on trying to find the report that was submitted to the ICF that landed us in Top 7 for 2011 (ICF's focus was health care last year)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily data/data collection, but here's a [video](http://uxweek.com/2010/videos/video-2010-chris-mccarthy-christi-zuber) from some of KP's representatives from UX Week 2010. It might point you in the right direction of things to consider/ideas to try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's gonna be a great tool in order to convinve my client that field work and ux design is important in health care :) I already saw one of the products designed for KP. It will be a great complement.